# handling multiple windows in selenium webdriver and what is WindowName

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How we can find the "WindowName" for specifying it in driver.switchTo().window(windowName); method.. I couldn't find the window's name anywhere.

Comment: What have you all tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from window name, windows can also be identified by window handles. Hence your syntax for switching to window will be:

```
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
```

you can get window handles of all windows by following and can switch to window you want by selecting respective window handle:

```
Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

If your html code something like following:

```
<button id="helpbutton" onClick='window.open("help.html","HelpWindow","width=500,height=500");'>Help</button>
```

in this case, "HelpWindow" is window name.