# Selenium webdriver | driver().switchTo().defaultContent() method is not switching the control back to parent window from multiple child windows

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, automation, webdriver

Selenium webdriver | `driver().switchTo().defaultContent()` method is not switching the control back to parent window from multiple child windows.

I am facing problem with respect to no of windows and not frames. When I click a button on parent window say wp, a new web window say w1 is getting generated and eventually one more window gets generated say w2 , I want to switch to control to wp so I am using

```
driver.switchTo.defaultContent()
```

but its not switching control to parent window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378716/handling-multiple-windows-in-selenium-webdriver-and-what-is-windowname . this can help

Comment: Can you try this `driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[0].toString());` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have this problem to.
and i find answer
try this, and give me feedback - maybe i can help you

```
 const number1 = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath('your xpath')))
      await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", number1).then(() =>{
        console.log(driver.executeScript, 'Click done');
      })
```

Comment: worked ... thank you Andrey kurkula

Comment: good luck my friend)

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for switching to window **tabs** or **iframe** ?

**for frames** : we need to do,

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo.parentFrame();
```

**for windows :**

```
String parentwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
List<String> allwindows = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(allwindows.get(1));
driver.switchTo().window(parentwindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two similar methods that can be used while switching to parent frames, but there is a slight difference between them.

`driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`
`driver.switchTo().parentFrame()`

E.g.: You have three frames i1,i2,i3 and you are on frame i3,
when you use **`driver.switchTo.defaultContent()`**, it will take you to i1, whereas with
**`driver.switchTo.parentFrame()`** control will switch to i2 i.e. immediate parent frame (parent frame of the current frame).

Comment: Hi Srinivas, Thanks for your answer but I ma facing problem with respect to no of windows and not frames. 
When i click a button on parent window say wp, a new web window say w1 is getting generated and eventually one more window gets generated say w2 , I want to switch te control to wp so i am using driver.switchTo.defaultContent() but its not switching control to parent window.

Comment: Then you must use the window handles concept in selenium. Useful link : https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/window-handle-in-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

If the process opens multiple browser tabs, we need to use `switchTo().window(window reference);` to switch focus between the tabs.

```
// Save the initial tab as parentwindow 
String parentwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Collect the tabs opened in a list
List<String> windows = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());

// Switch to window other than parentwindow
driver.switchTo().window(windows.get(1));

// Switch back to parentwindow
driver.switchTo().window(parentwindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using RemoteWebDriver for my cloud session where VM were running tests. Locally, it worked for me using  $ driver.switchTo().defaultContent() $, but all of a sudden, it did not work with RemoteWebDriver. I resolved my issue using:

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```